# Zend framework 3 and rackspace authenticate() is not working

Tags: php, zend-framework3, rackspace

This code was working fine with zf2 but when i migrated to ZF3 it is giving me the following error

```
$user = 'username';
$key  = 'secret key';

$rackspace = new ZendService\Rackspace\Files($user,$key);

if ($rackspace->authenticate()) {
    printf("Authenticated with token: %s",$rackspace->getToken());
} else {
    printf("ERROR: %s",$rackspace->getErrorMsg());
}
```

> File : zendframework\zendservice-rackspace\library\ZendService\Rackspace\AbstractRackspace.php:365
>
> Message: Call to a member function getFieldValue() on boolean

The error is from the Rackspace library, I haven't use getFieldValue() anywhere

Comment: What did you try? Relevant code is not in question. Error is clear as day: you're using the function `getFieldValue()` somewhere on a variable which is a `boolean` and not an `object`.

Comment: No i havn't used `getFieldValue()` anywhere, If you look closer the error is reporting in library itself not my written code

Comment: `Message: Call to a member function getFieldValue() on boolean` - You're really going to have to debug your code to figure out where this is getting called, because it is. Most likely during your upgrade from ZF2 to ZF3 you've not used locked vendor versions, so the Rackspace module also got upgraded to a new (major) version and now has different requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IN the Library itself there is a line that was causing the error

The `line 401` in `AbstractRackspace.php`

```
$this->managementUrl = $result->getHeaders()->get(self::MANAGEMENT_URL)->getFieldValue();
```

the error was due to this line as the `MANAGEMENT_URL` is not set there in the header. i commented that line in the file and the error is gone